# Displaying Plotly maps on disconnected system

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I am trying to use Plotly in a Jupyter notebook on a completely disconnected system (no internet access at all).  I am able to use basic bar and line charts, but the maps don't display at all.  Occasionally I get the legend, but not map or data.

Using the browser debugger, I found that the code is trying to download the templates from the web.  In the Plotly [documentation](https://plot.ly/python/renderers/) it states that by changing the default renderer to "notebook" that it should work completely offline.  That did nothing for me.

This is the sample code from the Plotly docs that I was trying to display.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('2011_february_us_airport_traffic.csv')
df['text'] = df['airport'] + '' + df['city'] + ', ' + df['state'] + '' + 'Arrivals: ' + df['cnt'].astype(str)

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scattergeo(
        lon = df['long'],
        lat = df['lat'],
        text = df['text'],
        mode = 'markers',
        marker_color = df['cnt'],
        ))

fig.update_layout(
        title = 'Most trafficked US airports<br>(Hover for airport names)',
        geo_scope='usa',
    )
fig.show()
```

Thoughts?

Comment: refer https://medium.com/@plotlygraphs/plotly-py-4-0-is-here-offline-only-express-first-displayable-anywhere-fc444e5659ee

Comment: @Shijith - The "offline" mode discussed there is different.  Quoted from the site, "Prior versions of plotly contained functionality for creating figures in both “online” and “offline” modes. In “online” mode, figures were uploaded to an instance of Plotly’s Chart Studio service and then displayed, whereas in “offline” mode figures were rendered locally."  So their definition of offline meant that it wasn't rendering it with online libraries.  However, for my case, it is still reaching out to download from https://cdn.plot.ly/world_110m.json.  That will not work in a truly disconnected system/